# Как мне удалить элемент из отфильтрованного или отсортированного списка RecyclerView?

Tags: android, сортировка, recyclerview, фильтрация, recyclerviewadapter

У меня есть RecyclerView, данные в котором можно отсортировать или отфильтровать. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было удалить элемент из отфильтрованного списка и этот же элемент удалился из оригинальных данных.

Я создал собственный адаптер.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Task task = data.get(position);
    holder.txtName.setText(task.getName());
    holder.txtDate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(task.getDate()));
    holder.chbDone.setChecked(task.isDone());
    holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        context.startActivity(intent) ;
    });
    holder.parentLayout.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
        data.remove(position); // удаление из неотфильтрованного массива данных
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        return true;
    });
}
```

Судя по всему, получать доступ к элементам можно только по позиции. Изменятся ли позиции элементов, когда список будет отфильтрован, т.е. когда будут отображаться не все элементы? Если так, то удалив элемент списка, я удалю совершенно не соответствующий ему объект. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position)`
позиция здесь, согласно [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onbindviewholder):

> Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position. This method should update the contents of the itemView to reflect the item at the given position.

будет корректной позицией в данных только на время вызова этого метода. При удалении элемента корректнее всего использовать метод [`ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getadapterposition):

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Task task = data.get(position);
    ...
    holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("position", holder.getAdapterPosition());
        context.startActivity(intent) ;
    });
    holder.parentLayout.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
        data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    });
}
```

Так же нужно учитывать, что [`ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getadapterposition) может вернуть позицию [`RecyclerView.NO_POSITION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#no_position), поэтому нужны соответствующие проверки.

Answer (score 0):

`notifyItemRemoved(position)` вызывает анимацию удаления из списка.
После удаления элемента списка нужно вызвать `notifyItemRangeChanged()`

```
data.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
```